# How not to expose App secret and key on a pure HTML5 client application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey

What could be a solution for a pure HTML/JavaScript client not to expose an application key and secret when using Baas like [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/).

In the example code https://github.com/KinveyApps/TestDrive-Angular/blob/master/index.html the app secret and key is exposed to the client, where anyone can see it.

Comment: short answer is you can't

Comment: fetch it from the server at runtime

Comment: @rupps even then it can be intercepted and viewed in the browsers dev tools. My understanding is the app secret is kept on the server and never sent to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version - You can't.

The longer version - You can't. It shouldn't stress you as it doesn't pose a security risk to your setup or data.

**Explanation:**

Kinvey app key and app secret on their own are allowed only few actions like
 - Ping your Kinvey app (confirm web/mobile app setup and back-end connectivity)
 - User login/signup (establish user session)

For all other actions that can view or modify your setup or data (e.g. collection access, business logic execution, triggering push notifications etc.), require a user session on top of app secret.

So even if you expose the app secret, it won't be an issue/threat in any way.

Comment: The solution we had was to enforce login on the client, that is client-side authentication without any server